# Actor's position sometimes not changes

Tags: android, libgdx, scene2d

I tried almost everything that I could, but I still can't understand this. I am changing actor's height and y when a bottom ad is loaded, using one of these methods: setPosition+setSize, setY+setHeight and setBounds. Almost every time (7 times from 10) height changes but position is not(!). I use adListener which calls onAdLoad method in my Game class, which calls onAdLoad method in the Screen. I placed  Gdx.app.log which writes y coordinate of the actor at the end of onAdLoad (Screen) method, it writes new y which is right, but when I write y coordinate from render method, it is 0. Please help me with this.

Some code:

AndroidLauncher class onCreate method:

```
    adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            Gdx.app.log("AdView:", "AdLoaded");
            if (adView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
                game.onAdLoad(adView.getHeight());
        }
    });
```

Game class:

```
public void onAdLoad(int adHeight) {
    adsHeight = adHeight;
    MyScreen activeScreen = ((MyScreen) getScreen());
    if (activeScreen != null) {
        activeScreen.onAdLoad();
    }
}
```

MyScreen interface:

```
public interface MyScreen extends Screen {
    void onAdLoad();
}
```

and one of the screens:

```
private Table mainMenu;

@Override
public void onAdLoad() {
    float adsHeight = MyGdxGame.adsHeight;
//        mainMenu.setBounds(0, adsHeight, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - adsHeight);
    Gdx.app.log("onAdLoad",adsHeight+"");
    mainMenu.setHeight(Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - adsHeight);
    mainMenu.setY(adsHeight);
    Gdx.app.log("onAdLoad", mainMenu.getY() + "");
//        mainMenu.setPosition(0, adsHeight);
//        mainMenu.setSize(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - adsHeight);
//        mainMenu.layout();
}
```

UPD: This is not working too:

```
public void onAdLoad() {
    //...
    stage.getActors().clear();
    stage.addActor(mainMenu);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried calling requestLayout() on your Actor after setting new position to it? And please provide us with some code and explanation. It's really hard to judge on what's going on.

Comment: I tried actor.layout() at the end of onAdLoad, it did no help.

Comment: have you tried removing and adding the actor again to the stage?

Comment: Yes, I tried it, it is not working.

Comment: No more suggestions? I really need help on this!